# Using bluetooth in phonegap

Tags: cordova, bluetooth

Ive done some googling and till now havent found a way to use bluetooth on a device using phonegap.

Are there any other API's/frameworks/platforms I should look at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way is to use (or create) a Phonegap plugin, which will deal with native Android class communicating with your Javascript.

Here is a [Github project](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth) which I found few weeks ago, but I didn't used it.

[How to work with bluetooth in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html);
[How to create a Phonegap plugin](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android).

Comment: Link down.. 2 years ago :(